# make: g++-4.7: Command not found.Error (Error 127) on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu

I try to deploy a CryptDB on Ubuntu 20.04 with help in this git repo: "https://github.com/yiwenshao/Practical-Cryptdb". The author's instruction was clear but it was deployed with the old version of some app(s) like g++ (which is g++-4.7). So I got it going till the last step and I got this error:

```
    g++-4.7 -MD -g -O0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-rtti -fwrapv -fPIC -Wall -Werror -W                                                                       pointer-arith -Wendif-labels -Wformat=2 -Wextra -Wmissing-noreturn -Wwrite-strin                                                                       gs -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-deprecated -Wmissing-declarations -Woverloaded-vir                                                                       tual -Wunreachable-code -D_GNU_SOURCE -std=c++0x -I/root/Practical-Cryptdb -I/ro                                                                       ot/Practical-Cryptdb/mysql-src/build/include -I/root/Practical-Cryptdb/mysql-src                                                                       /include -I/root/Practical-Cryptdb/mysql-src/sql -I/root/Practical-Cryptdb/mysql                                                                       -src/regex -I/root/Practical-Cryptdb/mysql-src/build/sql -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DMYSQL                                                                       _SERVER -DEMBEDDED_LIBRARY -DDBUG_OFF -DMYSQL_BUILD_DIR=\"/root/Practical-Cryptd                                                                       b/mysql-src/build\" -c crypto/BasicCrypto.cc -o obj/crypto/BasicCrypto.o
    make: g++-4.7: Command not found
    make: *** [Makefile:73: obj/crypto/BasicCrypto.o] Error 127
    g++-4.7 -MD -g -O0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-rtti -fwrapv -fPIC -Wall -Werror -W                                                                       pointer-arith -Wendif-labels -Wformat=2 -Wextra -Wmissing-noreturn -Wwrite-strin                                                                       gs -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-deprecated -Wmissing-declarations -Woverloaded-vir                                                                       tual -Wunreachable-code -D_GNU_SOURCE -std=c++0x -I/root/Practical-Cryptdb -I/ro                                                                       ot/Practical-Cryptdb/mysql-src/build/include -I/root/Practical-Cryptdb/mysql-src                                                                       /include -I/root/Practical-Cryptdb/mysql-src/sql -I/root/Practical-Cryptdb/mysql                                                                       -src/regex -I/root/Practical-Cryptdb/mysql-src/build/sql -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DMYSQL                                                                       _SERVER -DEMBEDDED_LIBRARY -DDBUG_OFF -DMYSQL_BUILD_DIR=\"/root/Practical-Cryptd                                                                       b/mysql-src/build\" -c udf/edb.cc -o obj/udf/edb.o
    make: g++-4.7: Command not found
    make: *** [Makefile:73: obj/udf/edb.o] Error 127
```

I did try to install `GCC-4.7` and `g++-4.7` but no work.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with makefiles; you should remove the makefile tab.  If you need to use GCC 4.7 then you'll have to install it.  If you can't install it and must have it, then you'll have to either find an already-built copy or else build GCC yourself.  Probably it's better to find some software that is maintained well enough that it works with modern versions of the compiler and doesn't require ancient versions.  Or maybe it would actually work with newer compilers, in which case you can try running `make CXX=g++` to override the compiler name.

Comment: @MadScientist tks, i removed the tag. Yes, i did try to install g++-4.7 and got it installed but some how it still does not work :<

Comment: Maybe the instructions you're following are bad? Either you extract a [mcve] and post that here or you file a bugticket upstream.

Comment: If you installed it but `g++-4.7` says "command not found" then you'll have to figure out where it got installed (and make sure that directory is on your `PATH`) and what the name of the compiler is (and use that instead of `g++-4.7` if it's different).

Comment: "Practical-Cryptdb" seems to be for Ubuntu 16.04 only : See README.md → `you need follow the following steps → have ubuntu 16.04 installed` etc.